# Rendering each value from a firebase array into <li> with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm working on a recipe app and I'm having some issues rendering my ingredient list from a Firebase array.  I'm new to JS and React, so i apologize if this is something simple. I really appreciate any help that's provided! I've attached my code and an example of how the array is currently being rendered. I've also included a screenshot of the Firebase data structure. [firebaseStructure][1]

```js
useEffect(() =>{

  database.collection('recipes').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    setRecipeCard(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({id:doc.id, recipes:doc.data()})));
    console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({id:doc.id, recipes:doc.data()})))
  })  
  }, []);

  useEffect(() =>{
    
    database.collection('recipes').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{

      setIngredientsList(snapshot.docs.map(doc =>({id:doc.id, ingredient: doc.data().ingredients1})));
      console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc =>({id:doc.id, ingredient: doc.data().ingredients1})))
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
      <Row>

      {recipeCard.map(recipes =>(
      
        <Col md={4} key={recipes.id}>
          <Card style={{ width: '100%' }}>
              <Card.Img variant="top" src={recipes.recipes.url} style={{height:'300px',width:'100%'}} />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{recipes.recipes.title}</Card.Title>
                {/**<Card.Text> **/}
                <ul key={recipes.id}>
                  {ingredientsList.map(recipes =>(
                  <li key={recipes.id}>
                      {recipes.ingredient}
                  </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
                {/** </Card.Text> **/}
              <Button variant="secondary">Head to Recipe</Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          </Col>   
          
      ))}
      </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

[current rendered output][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFBdr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU1fC.png
```

Comment: Please share console.log for ingredientsList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of the confusion here has come from the naming convention, and the attempt to use separate state for the `recipieCard` and `ingredientsList`. You've ended up rendering all the ingredients for all recipies instead of just the one's relevant to that recipie. If you ever find yourself accessing properties like `recipies.recipies`, you know you need to do some refactoring (if you have complete control of the project).

First things first, you only need one `useEffect` to access your database and process the data. It all belongs together, so there's no need to separate it into separate states. Notice how I've renamed the state as `recipieCards` plural. This is an array or list of data objects, so it should have a pluralised name. Each data object now has the property `data` instead of `recipies`, which more accurately describes what it contains (i.e. the data for ONE recipie).

```
useEffect(() =>{
  database.collection('recipes').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setRecipeCards(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({id:doc.id, data:doc.data()})));
      console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({id:doc.id, data:doc.data()})))
  })  
}, []);
```

Now in the return fuction it becomes much more clear what's going on. We take the array of `recipieCards` and map over it to access each recipie data object one at a time. For each data object use the `id` as its key, and take the url and title from `data`. Now you can access that recipie's ingredients directly from the same data object, under the property `data.ingredients1`.

```
return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {recipeCards.map(recipe =>(
              <Col md={4} key={recipe.id}>
                  <Card style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                      <Card.Img variant="top" src={recipe.data.url} style={{height:'300px',width:'100%'}} />
                      <Card.Body>
                          <Card.Title>{recipe.data.title}</Card.Title>
                           {/**<Card.Text> **/}
                              <ul>
                                  {recipie.data.ingredients1.map(ingredient =>(
                                      <li key={ingredient}>
                                          {ingredient}
                                      </li>
                                  ))}
                              </ul>
                           {/** </Card.Text> **/}
                          <Button variant="secondary">Head to Recipe</Button>
                      </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
              </Col>       
          ))}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: you're a rockstar, sir.  Thank you for the help and the SUPER useful explanations there!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the DB twice in two separate `useEffect` to do what you want. You should only call the DB once for efficiency in this case.

Also, you're re declaring `recipes` within the second map, this could cause errors, you should avoid using the same variable name for different variables. Your problem may be related to this. I edited the following code assuming you only use the first `useEffect` with `setRecipeCard`.

```
{recipeCard.map(recipe =>(
  <Col md={4} key={recipe.id}>
    <Card style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={recipe.recipes.url} style={{height:'300px',width:'100%'}} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{recipe.recipes.title}</Card.Title>
          {/**<Card.Text> **/}
            <ul key={recipe.id}>
              {recipe.ingredients1.map(ingredient =>(
                <li key={recipes.id}>
                  {ingredient}
                </li>
               ))}
             </ul>
             {/** </Card.Text> **/}
             <Button variant="secondary">Head to Recipe</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  </Col>        
))}
```

Can you try out this code? Please let us know specifically if you are getting any errors :)